# Laravel: how to upload pdf file directly to Google Cloud Storage bucket without first saving it locally

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-storage, laravel-8

I am using the [`google/cloud-storage`](https://packagist.org/packages/google/cloud-storage) package in an API and successfully uploading pdf files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. However, the pdf files are first saved locally before they are uploaded to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

How can I skip saving them locally and instead upload them directly to the Google Cloud Storage bucket? I am planning to host the API on Google App Engine.
This is the [post](https://dev.to/ediri_aghwotu/how-to-upload-files-to-google-cloud-using-laravel-3618) for it.

This is what I am doing currently:

```php
$filename = $request['firstname'] . '.pdf';
$fileStoragePath = '/storage/pdf/' . $filename;
$publicPath = public_path($fileStoragePath);

$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('pdfdocument', $validatedData)
$pdf->save($publicPath); 

$googleConfigFile = file_get_contents(config_path('googlecloud.json'));
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFile' => json_decode($googleConfigFile, true)
]);
$storageBucketName = config('googlecloud.storage_bucket');
$bucket = $storage->bucket($storageBucketName);
$fileSource = fopen($publicPath, 'r');
$newFolderName = $request['firstname'].'_'.date("Y-m-d").'_'.date("H:i:s");
$googleCloudStoragePath = $newFolderName.'/'.$filename;

/*
*  Upload a file to the bucket.
*  Using Predefined ACLs to manage object permissions, you may
*  upload a file and give read access to anyone with the URL.
*/
$bucket->upload($fileSource, [
    'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',
    'name' => $googleCloudStoragePath
]);
```

Is it possible to upload files to a Google Cloud Storage bucket without first saving them locally?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you write the article linked in your question? Nice article. I do not know the DOMPDF library, but Google Cloud Storage PHP SDK supports the PSR StreamInterface. If your PDF library supports the `StreamInterface`, then you can link them together. http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.23.1/storage/bucket?method=upload AND https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/1.0.1/src/StreamInterface.php

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I wrote the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not verified this code, but the class PDF member `output()` returns a string.

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('pdfdocument', $validatedData)

...

$bucket->upload($pdf->output(), [
    'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',
    'name' => $googleCloudStoragePath
]);
```

You can simply the client code. Replace:

```
$googleConfigFile = file_get_contents(config_path('googlecloud.json'));
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFile' => json_decode($googleConfigFile, true)
]);
```

with

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => config_path('googlecloud.json')
]);
```